# Winforms Databound Combobox updates data but does not change RowState

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

.NET 4.7.2 Winforms c#

Have a form with a bunch of comboboxes.  DropDownList for all.  Comboboxes are populated from either Datatables or dictionaries.  They are bound to columns in a datatable for the dataset.

Comboboxes populated and databound like this:

```
        dSDO = new Dictionary<bool, string>
        {
            {true,"Yes" },
            {false,"No" }
        };
        CB1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dSDO, null);;
        CB1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        CB1.ValueMember = "Key";
        CB2.DataSource = _dtCommodity;
        CB2.DisplayMember = "CommodityAbbr";
        CB2.ValueMember = "CommodityID";
        // Databindings tried both before and after 
        CB1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", dataset, "Tablename.colname1", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        CB1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", dataset, 'Tablename.colname2", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Selecting a different item in the ComboBox updates the column in the data row.  However, the RowState remains unchanged and the update for the row does not happen. Expressly calling ValidateChildren for the form does nothing.

This code used to work in older .NET frameworks (4.0 and older); it seems that something has changed to break the processing or I am missing something and Microsoft is not so forgiving anymore.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you called `dataset.AcceptChanges();` after you've loaded the data (to set the status of all Rows to `Unchanged`)? Also, I'd use a BindingSource to handle the DataSet (set the DataSet as its DataSource) and use the BindingSource to bind the ComboBox (set the `DataSource` member of the Binding to the BindingSource). Binding to a nested object will work this way. The Row status will be `Modified` when you commit a value through the ComboBox. The DataSource of the ComboBox should be an object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (there are no `ListChanged` events there).

Comment: I don't call AcceptChanges -- That would set the status to unchanged.

I will immediately try the suggestion.

Comment: When you first load the data, you should set the status to `Unchanged`, otherwise it remain `Added`, which is not true. The DataAdapter has a property, `[DataAdapter].AcceptChangesDuringFill`, which is used exactly for this.

Comment: My problem is that is still shows unchanged after data is changed.  I change the selection in the ComboBox, the combobox new selectedvalue is written to the dataRow but the RowState is unchanged.  Changing the databindings of the fields to a bindingSource over the dataset did no good whatsoever.  Same result.

Comment: Add a BindingSource as a Field (e.g., `internal BindingSource bsDataSet = null;`), then  `bsDataSet = new BindingSource(dataset, null); CB1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsDataSet, "Tablename.colname1", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`. Of course you add just one `DataBinding`, if you try to add a second you get an exception. BTW, always set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` (in this order) **before** the `DataSource`.

Comment: I found the issue.  Will post a self-answer in a short while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Pursuant to a suggestion from @Jimi, I changed the code...

```
        bsDataSource = new BindingSource(dataSet, "[SqlTableName]");
        CB1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsDataSource, "colname1", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        CB2.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", bsDataSource, "colname2", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

And then in the save, I did this:

```
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommandObject))
                {
                    using (SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da))
                    {
                        da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
                        cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
                        cb.SetAllValues = false;
                       
                        da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand(true);
                        da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
                        da.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand(true);
                        try
                        {
                            // I Added this line
                            ((DataRowView)bsDataSource.Current).EndEdit();
                            // End of what I added
                            da.MissingMappingAction = MissingMappingAction.Passthrough;
                            iRowCount = da.Update(ds, ds.Tables[0].TableName);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            // [error handling]
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This caused the RowState to change to Modified and the dataset update to succeed.

So the solution:

1. Make a BindingSource over the DataSet object, with the TableName of
   the relevant DataTable as Parameter 2
2. DataBind each control to the relevant column name and specifying the BindingSource.
3. Execute EndEdit() over the DataRowView that is in the Current property.
4. Then do the DataAdapter update.

Thanks - Hope that this helps someone else.